# Filter a Collection on LINQ with Recursion

Tags: linq, collections, recursion, filter

I have a collection named as **MenuItemCollection** and this derived form **List< MenuItem >**

There is a Singleton Instance of **MenuItemCollection** and if I simplify the fields of **MenuItem**:

```
public class MenuItem
{
   int Id {set;get;}
   string Title {set;get;}
   MenuItemCollection ChildMenus {set;get;}
}
```

I need to use a **filter** method on this collection. For example, I'd like to filter the collection for one menu's Id.
Here is a sample MenuItemCollection:

```
1-Home
2-User Menu
  4-Update Info
  5-Delete Account
3-News
  6-Archived News
```

As you can see there some **Child** menus such as *number 4* or *number 6*

I normally use below to filter:

```
public List<MenuItem> Filter(MenuItemFilterArgs args)
{
     List<MenuItem> Result = new List<MenuItem>();
     IQueryable<MenuItem> QueryableTemp = this.AsQueryable();

     return (from item in QueryableTemp
                      orderby item.Ordering descending
                      select item).ToList<MenuItem>();
}
```

And calling this method as:

```
var FilteredMenus = MenuItemCollection.GetInstance.Filter(new MenuItemFilterArgs { Id = 5 });
```

Since *number 5* is in an inner collection under *number 2* menuitem, the result returns as 0. It cannot be found.

How is it possible to run the filter recursively through inner MenuItemCollections? Could you write a code sample?

> PS: If you must know why I'm using a singleton instance; my idea was
>   to retrieve the menus from database and keep it as an object for
>   easier and faster usage on run-time.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can probably do this much easier by querying the original source of menu items, before they are used to build the tree.

Comment: But that's the thing, I don't wanna go back to database all the time.. Its the main reason why I use singleton.. I should be querying the database unless there is an update, add or delete over the menus.. And besides, there will be a lot of filtering through out the website operations.

Comment: No, but you could hang on to your original collection in your singleton.

Comment: This menu collection includes many menus in different parts of website. For example, in the singleton instance, ALL menus are inside but on the RIGHT side of the page there is a RIGHTMENU and this rightmenu should be filtered from the original singleton without going back to database. There is also a TopMenu and a Left menu and a BottomMenu... The menus are also filtered by their languageId's... But in the end, the singleton must include all menu (which in this case it does) but the parts of the website should call ONLY the related menus by filtering the main singleton.

Comment: I don't understand your `Filter()` method. It doesn't use `args` or `Result` and I don't see any reason to use `AsQueryable()` there.

Comment: Yes you don't see the args used in that method but its only because I just simplified the code.. Normally it is used.. Right now I'm trying the other answer who was kind enough to help with a clean code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example.  The ExtensionMethods.Map method is what you need.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var menuItems1 = MenuItemCollection.Instance.Filter(null);
            var menuItems2 = MenuItemCollection.Instance.Filter(new MenuItemCriteria { Id = 5 });
            var menuItems3 = MenuItemCollection.Instance.Filter(new MenuItemCriteria { Title = "News" });
            var menuItems4 = MenuItemCollection.Instance.Filter(new MenuItemCriteria { Title = "News", IsTrash = true });
        }
    }

    public class MenuItemCollection : List<MenuItem>
    {
        public static readonly MenuItemCollection Instance;

        static MenuItemCollection()
        {
            Instance = GetMenuList();
        }

        static MenuItemCollection GetMenuList()
        {
            return new MenuItemCollection {
                new MenuItem {Id = 1, Title = "Home"},
                new MenuItem {Id = 2, Title = "User Menu", ChildMenus = new MenuItemCollection { 
                        new MenuItem { Id = 4, Title = "Update Info"},
                        new MenuItem { Id = 5, Title = "Delete"}
                    }},
                new MenuItem {Id = 3, Title = "News", ChildMenus = new MenuItemCollection { 
                        new MenuItem { Id = 6, Title = "Archived News"},
                        new MenuItem { Id = 6, Title = "Trashy News", IsTrash = true}
                    }},
            };
        }

        public List<MenuItem> Filter(MenuItemCriteria criteria)
        {
            var expression = PredicateBuilder.True<MenuItem>();

            if(criteria != null)
            {
                if (criteria.Id.HasValue)
                {
                    expression = expression.And(menuItem => menuItem.Id == criteria.Id);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Title))
                {
                    expression = expression.And(menuItem => menuItem.Title.Contains(criteria.Title));
                }

                if (criteria.IsTrash.HasValue)
                {
                    expression = expression.And(menuItem => menuItem.IsTrash == criteria.IsTrash);
                }
            }

            Func<MenuItem, bool> searchCriteria = expression.Compile();
            Func<MenuItem, IEnumerable<MenuItem>> childrenSelector = x => x.ChildMenus;

            return this.Map(searchCriteria, childrenSelector).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class MenuItemCriteria
    {
        public int? Id { set; get; }
        public string Title { set; get; }
        public bool? IsTrash { set; get; }
    }

    public class MenuItem
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Title { set; get; }
        public bool IsTrash { set; get; }
        public MenuItemCollection ChildMenus { set; get; }
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Map<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                            Func<T, bool> selector = null,
                                            Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector = null)
        {
            if (source == null) return new List<T>();

            if (selector == null)
            {
                // create a default selector that selects all items
                selector = x => true;
            }

            var list = source.Where(selector);

            if (childrenSelector != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in source)
                {
                    list = list.Concat(childrenSelector(item).Map(selector, childrenSelector));
                }
            }

            return list;
        }
    }

    public static class PredicateBuilder
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
        {
            var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                  (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                             Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
        {
            var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                  (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This really is awesome!! Is it possible to add search criteria if it has been filled? For example, there could be several other criterias like MenuTitle or IsActive.. But not all them may be provided into search criteria:



for example doing like in Filter method:
if(menuItem.Id.HasValue)
 // Add Id criteria into search
if(menuItem.Title != string.empty)
 // Add Title criteria into search

Comment: Yes, that is possible.  You should check out http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx.  This will help you with building up the search criteria.

Comment: I've been working on this link you gave me for several hours. Thanks to you and the link you gave me, I now have a better understanding on predicates. However, despite my efforts, I could not manage to combine with your code.. Here is a link what I've tried and I've wanted to: http://i1143.photobucket.com/albums/n624/Creador83/Question1.jpg

Thank you very much Tom Brothers...

Comment: I think what you were missing was converting the search criteria *expression* to a search criteria *function*.  I update the sample code to include this conversion.

Comment: Yes yes and yes!.. This is 100% what I was trying to do. I just didn't know this code: expression.Compile(); "Compile" I meant. Your code is clean, simple, very understandable and working perfectly. I sincerely thank you...